# s4 galaxy phone update gone bad

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

my phone was updating but was disconnected.Now it is only showing " software update failed" with a phone symbol and a command sign with a computer next. whats has gone wrong?

Comment: Some more info please? As what android versions you were upgrading from and to?

Answer (score 0):

Since updating process didin't complete as expected, Then it's normal to see that sign, In order to recover the phone to it's original state, You'll have to flash it with it's original Firmware using the official tools from Samsung called "Odin", You need two thing (Odin and Firmware), For the Firmware you can always download any of Samsung Firmwares from [Sammobile](http://sammobile.com) -they need you to be a registered user but it's free-, And download the latest version of the Firmware and it's 5.0.1, Now for Odin you can download the latest one from [Odin_All_Versions](http://androidxda.net/download-odin-rom-flashing-tool-for-all-samsung-smartphones/), Once you have all the files needed you can start the process by following this guide,

1. Extract the Firmware and Odin to the same folder
2. Power off the Phone
3. Boot the phone into Download Mode by pressing (Vol-, Home and Power button)
4. Connect the phone to the PC using USB cable
5. Run Odin as Admin
6. Click on (AP) from Odin then choose the Firmware file
7. Click (START) and leave it do it's things
8. After process done you'll see a green "PASS" sign
9. Now your phone will Reboot one time to "Recovery" and the second one to "System"